# Cant load object in ApplicationUser Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I'm creating an application in C# that uses Identity. 
I created my own ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public UserRole HighestRole { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

}
```

I also created a Usermanager:

```
public class UserManager : UserManager<Gebruiker>
{
    public UserManager(IUserStore<Gebruiker> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static UserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<UserManager> options,IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new UserManager(new UserStore<Gebruiker>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<Gebruiker>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<Gebruiker>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

But if I want to get a user out of my database, the UserRole object is always null

this is how I get the user out of the database.

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(correctId);
```

CODE:
[image]
SAME TIME IN DATABASE:
[image]

Comment: Refer to [Forcing EF ApplicationUser To Load Navigation Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102708/forcing-ef-applicationuser-to-load-navigation-properties#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public virtual UserRole HighestRole { get; set; }
```